# MyRocks Compilation Issue

Tags: mysql, rocksdb, lz4

The error is

```
my_compress.c:542: undefined reference to `LZ4F_resetDecompressionContext'
```

My os is centos 7.7.1908 and I have installed lz4 by `yum install -y lz4-devel`. The install directory is as follows:

```
work@ost:~/workspace/mysql-5.6/bld $ ls /usr/lib64/liblz*
/usr/lib64/liblz4.so  /usr/lib64/liblz4.so.1  /usr/lib64/liblz4.so.1.7.5  /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5  /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.2

work@ost:~/workspace/mysql-5.6/bld $ ls /usr/include/lz4*
/usr/include/lz4frame.h  /usr/include/lz4.h  /usr/include/lz4hc.h
```

Comment: Rephrase the title to indicate that there is a problem rather than a literal error message. Move the error message into the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer. The version of lz4 is too old. Please see it here(https://github.com/facebook/mysql-5.6/issues/1114)